# Css and javascript minifiers for download or online

Tags: javascript, css, bandwidth, minify

Looking for both css and javascript minifiers which are either for file download to run on the computer or single use online.

Ive done the google search thing, but wondered if theres any which come recommended??

Comment: http://refresh-sf.com/yui/

Comment: http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **[code beautifier](http://www.codebeautifier.com/)**, **[CSS Beautify](http://cssbeautify.com/)** and **[JS Beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/)**

This is what I personally use and it has assisted me a lot.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, codebeautifier is a great tool and will certainly be using that again. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yslow/
that can help you

i have installed it to found the external files , css, images , scripts.
and that also minified the css files that tool can minified

Answer (score 0):

You can find js beautify/minify at http://codebeautify.org/jsviewer/ and css beautify/minify at http://codebeautify.org/cssviewer also you can file other tools for developer at

These tools supports Loading data from url.

Copy and paste the data and user can also open files from local computer and test.

Comment: A little more explanation might help out the fellow programmers to understand how the links work.

Comment: these tools supports Loading data from url, Copy and paste data and user can also open files from local computer and test.